# CARTO Builder, make calculation based on map point set by user

Tags: carto

I'm have recent looking into carto in my search for a nice and powerful map analysis service.

I have set a few map nice, tidy and easy, but I'm missing an essential feature. 
I'm looking on a way to make the data analysis based on input from the a users and where they click or placed a pin somewhere in the map.

It could be something like calculate the population with a 30 min isoline, with origin from where the user click on the map.

I have been unable to find this feature in the carto builder.

Can someone confirm if there is no such possibilities or point out to me where I can find it ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, that's not possible to do it with BUILDER. You need to code a web application with CARTO.js. You have a blog post [here](https://carto.com/blog/read-and-write-to-cartodb-with-the-leaflet-draw-plugin), explaining how to build it, and an example similar to what you want to do [here](http://bl.ocks.org/andrewbt/24bf9d8cf7cf241b2472c0c91a976b89).